# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: " := . ( @ % ;"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, transactions

I have this code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY
 
        INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4)
        SELECT '1', field2, field3, field4
        FROM table1

COMMIT 
 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END CATCH
```

And I get this the following error

```
    SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
```

I have tried and looked for multiple questions regarding the same topic and I can't find the answer, maybe something is going over my head here. Using ; after each sentence gives me differents errors

UPDATE:

Following the error message ends with this code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY;
     
            INSERT INTO table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4)
            SELECT '1', field2, field3, field4
            FROM table1
    
    COMMIT ;
     
    END TRY;
    
    BEGIN CATCH;
    
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    
    END CATCH;
```

And the following error:

```
    SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 13, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-02181: invalid option to ROLLBACK WORK
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quote
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code you posted is **not** Oracle, while error message you got **is** so I presume you really use Oracle. In that case, you'd

```
begin
  insert into table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4)
  select '1', filed2, field3, field4
  from table1;
  
  commit;
end;
/
```

---

If there's an error, nothing will actually be inserted so no need to rollback. If you want, you can handle exceptions e.g.

```
begin
  insert into table2 (field1, field2, field3, field4)
  select '1', filed2, field3, field4
  from table1;
  
  commit;

exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, Will this rollback in case of any error without the need for more code?

Comment: I've just edited the message and added some more info. Have a look, please.

Comment: Your new edit gives me the feeling that I'm not achieving what I want with my code, What I'm pretending to do is insert multiple fields from multiple rows from a table, into multiple new rows in the second table. If one of these rows give me some errors, rollback the entire process.

Comment: The default behaviour for uncaught exceptions is to roll back open transactions, report the error and return failure. Therefore I'm not keen on `when others then raise;` as it pollutes the error stack.

Answer (score 1):

Please resolve one by one for the errors. For the error which you have mentioned, Keep a ';' after 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' and compile and check. Then based on further errors, you can check which line needs to be fixed, or what error needs to be fixed. Hope the approach helps.